# using external component in Nuxt not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have component I install from npm

it called `vue-3d-model`

I create a file like this `~/plugins/ModelGltf.js`

```
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import { ModelGltf } from 'vue-3d-model';

    Vue.use(ModelGltf)
```

and then I register it in `nuxt.config.js`

```
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/ModelGlft.js', ssr: false },
  ],
```

and I called in my component like `<model-gltf> ...........` 
but it was not rendering, in my console terminal it called `Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression` and in my inspect it said `<model-gltf>` component is not register yet

I have been saw some question on stack overflow and tried their answers , still can't work

Comment: This may help you - [issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/414#issuecomment-288881242)

Comment: I saw before I ask this,  but not work buddy

Answer (score 1):

try to this,

in your `~/plugins/ModelGltf.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { ModelGltf } from 'vue-3d-model';
Vue.component('ModelGltf', ModelGltf)
```

and then I register it in `nuxt.config.js`

```
{ src: '~/plugins/ModelGlft.js', ssr: false },
```

or

```
{ src: '@/plugins/ModelGlft.js', ssr: false },
```